# iOS Newbie: Need help understanding Core Graphics Layers

Tags: objective-c, ios5, core-graphics

A bit of a newbie question for iOS, just started learning about Core Graphics but I'm still not sure how it's integrated into the actual view

So I have a method that creates a CGLayer ref, draws some bezier curves on it, and then returns the CGLayer; here's a very condensed version of my procedure:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGLayerRef layer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(ctx, CGSizeMake(300.0,300.0), NULL);
CGContextRef layerCtx = CGLayerGetContext(layer);
```

Then I add some bezier fills that are dynamically generated by parsing an SVG file.

I've already verified that the SVG is being parsed properly, and I am using this code http://ponderwell.net/2011/05/converting-svg-paths-to-objective-c-paths/ to parse the path instructions (from the path tags' d parameters) into UIBezierPath objects

So I start by creating the fill

```
CGColorRef color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0].CGColor;
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(layerCtx, color);
```

Then adding the UIBezierPath

```
SvgToBezier *bezier = [[SvgToBezier alloc] initFromSVGPathNodeDAttr:pathAttr rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];

UIBezierPath *bezierPath = bezier.bezier;

CGContextAddPath(layerCtx, bezierPath.CGPath);
CGContextDrawPath(layerCtx, kCGPathFill);
```

And finally I return the CGLayerRef like so

```
return layer;
```

My question: Now that I have this layer ref, I want to draw it to a UIView (or whatever type of object would be best to draw to)

The ultimate goal is to have the layer show up in a UITableViewCell.

Also, the method I've described above exists in a class I've created from scratch (which inherits from NSObject). There is separate method which uses this method to assign the layer ref to a property of the class instance.

I would be creating this instance from the view controller connected to my table view. Then hopefully adding the layer to a UITableView cell within the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method.

I hope I included all of the relevant information and I greatly appreciate your help.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is the view you want to draw on's layer needs to be set to your newly created layer.

```
[myCurrentViewController.view setLayer:newLayer];
```

Long answer can be found in the excellent Quartz2D programming guide, found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_layers/dq_layers.html).

Comment: Ah, I see. So would it be most efficient to create a new layer and attach it to the view before I begin drawing my Bezier Curves? Or would it be better to draw on the new layer first, and then set it to the view? If you don't know I'd be happy to do a benchmark and post the results. Thanks for your answer; going to try it out now!

Comment: Hmm, this is a good question.  I'm not certain, so I won't guess, but I'm sure somewhere on SO this has been brought up.